# TFS how to move queued build to another build controller

Tags: build, tfs, controller, queue

We have TFS 2010 builds queued to be run on a build controller, which is not available anymore.

I've fixed the build definition to use the available controller, so all the further builds will go to the correct one.

But is there any way to move existing queued builds to be run on a different build controller?
Or should I just cancel them and re-request builds manually?

Comment: cancelling doesn't preserve the actual options that were requested, such as who it was requested by, I'd love to see a proper answer to this